# Laravel sail multiple databases

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I'm using laravel sail and trying to create another database for my Laravel project which required to use multiple databases connections, I've tried to create from user `root` with empty password and `sail` with `password` password but go access denied.
tried command line to run

`docker-compose exec -u 0 "mariadb" mysql -usail -ppassword -e 'create database databaseName;'`

but also got access denied.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding an additional volume in your docker-compose.yml file

```
volumes:
     - 'sail-mariadb:/var/lib/mysql'
     - ./docker/8.1/create-extra-database.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/create-extra-database.sql
     - './vendor/laravel/sail/database/mysql/create-testing-database.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/10-create-testing-database.sh'
```

Then make sure to have the `create-extra-database.sql` in the proper directory. Like this:
[image]

Then add whatever mysql commands you'd like in that file. Here I'm adding an additional log database.

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS log;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `log`.* TO 'sail'@'%';
```

Make sure to delete the previous mysql docker container and volume. Then run `sail up`

Answer (score -2):

i see you use mariadb
so type

`sail mariadb`

will open mariadb line command
type

```
create database name
```